# Detecting the button click on z-index -1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi this is my [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5dbLoepu/1/) code. There is an animation from right to left and then left to right when the animation stops then a car image appear from the bottom. i want to detect if the car image is clicked then i have to open a new window. The car image z-index is set -1 so that close button is visible but if i am not able to detect the click functionality. What can i do to make it work. 
When we clicked on the close button then it hides everything and shows a single div.

```
#car_slider {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:-10px;
    width:300px;
    height:0;
    border:2px solid #000;
    z-index: -1;

}
```

I tried using this line of code but it does not detect the click.

```
$("#car_slider").click(function() {
    window.open('//www.google.com', '_blank');
});
```

Comment: `#car_slider` will never be clicked. you have to change z-index of it

Comment: if i will change the z-index then close button will be disappear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put z-index:1;

```
    #car_slider {
        position:fixed;
        bottom:-10px;
        width:300px;
        height:0;
        border:2px solid #000;
        z-index: 1;
}
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5dbLoepu/3/)

Comment: now close button is not working can you check my close button it hides everything and shows a single div

Comment: check demo url i have added z-index on that.. z-index:9;

Comment: thanks but my close button is not working when i click on the close button it  opens a new page can you check my close button

Comment: chekc this and Comment this line also    //$(this).parent().hide();

https://jsfiddle.net/5dbLoepu/6/

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `z-index:-1` from `#car_slider` and `z-index:1;` from `#animate` solved your issue.

There is no need to set any `z-index` in your code.

**Edit:**

To make close button clickable set `z-index` to `#close_btn`

Check [Fiddle Here.](https://jsfiddle.net/5dbLoepu/4/)

**Update:**

For chrome youe have to set `z-index` for `#animate` div lower than `#close_btn` and it works.

Check [Updated Fiddle Here.](https://jsfiddle.net/5dbLoepu/7/)

Comment: Thanks but now if i click the close button then it is opening a new page and in my close button it will hide all the images and it will show a single div can you check my close button please

Comment: i think you did not get my point. Can you check my close please when i click it then it hides everything and shows a div

Comment: Yes same thing is working in my updated fiddle check. https://jsfiddle.net/5dbLoepu/4/. on close click it will close the div.

Comment: yes i see it is working in firefox only not in chrome

Comment: @user3754676 Ohh ok i got it. Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

I see what you mean, here you are. Use a conditional.

```
var linked = false;
moveLeft();            
$('#leave_panel').hide();
$("#logo").click(function() {
    window.open('//www.sizmek.com', '_blank');
});

$("#car_slider").css("z-index", "1").click(function() {
    if(linked === false){
        console.log("linked away!");
        linked = true;
    } else {
         $("#car_slider").css("z-index", "-1");
    }
```

This will check if the image is clicked, if so, it will link them away, and afterwards, they can also close the image.